# Class not working with static variable in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I have created a class with a static data member. But its not getting executed even the `.exe` file is not being created. I am using `Visual C++ express 2010`.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public: 
static int a;
};

int main()
{ 
    A::a = 10;
    cout << A::a;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

On compilation I am getting following errors:
`main.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A00038B) "public: static int A::a" (?a@A@@2HA)`

`1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int A::a" (?a@A@@2HA)`

`1>C:\Users\Labeeb\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\static variables and functions\Debug\static variables and functions.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`

Comment: please don't use `system("pause")`. It's bad practice.

Comment: Only the 50 millionth time this question has been asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add following to your source file:

```
int A::a;
```

`static` member variables need to be defined somewhere, outside of any function and after the declaration of the class.

Comment: Add it outside of any functions though.

Comment: @NikBougalis I updated my answer. For me very logical, but for beginners that may be important.